# how to use load data infile

Tags: mysql, linux, csv, load-data-infile

I'm trying to use the MySQL load data infle command, but whenever I use the command the following error appears:

```
09:28:22 LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/carlos/response.csv' into table user FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' Error Code: 29. File '/home/carlos/response.csv' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied).
```

I am not able to guarantee the necessary permission for mysql to be able to read the file. If anyone can help me I would be grateful.

I hope that mysql can read the csv file, I already changed the file's porpietario to mysql and still nothing.

Comment: I'm not really sure how we can help you as we are not aware what permissions the user running mysql has and what permissions you can grant on that specific directory / files.